# Where can I find a shapefile of zoning for the city of Phoenix and other municipalities?

Tags: data, united-states

Where can I find a shapefile of zoning for the city of Phoenix and other municipalities?  I would rather not have to geo-reference a picture and digitize over it, there must be some data already out there somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

I remember a paper or conference presentation from 3-4 years ago focused on ownership of government data. The discussion was framed in the context of the city of Phoenix invoking homeland security concerns in their refusal to release GIS data, even for classroom use within the city. I can't for the life of me remember the source -- 15 minutes of googling hasn't turned it up either.

Anyway, here's a link to the [Maricopa County Planning and Development Department's GIS page](http://planning.maricopa.gov/). Hope it's of some use to you.

EDIT: So I'll blame the fact that it was late when I posted above but I think I may have blended two distinct memories. The Arizona connection concerns Tempe, not Phoenix, and was discussed in [James Fee's Blog](http://www.spatiallyadjusted.com/2009/11/29/tempe-az-gis-data-it-will-cost-ya/). His beef with Tempe was over data cost and accessibility. Perhaps someone else remembers which municipality was restricting access to data by citing flimsy security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Strange how I can't drill down into [this rest endpoint](http://chandleraz.gov/GISServices/ArcGIS/rest/services) used by [City of Chandler infomap](http://infomap.chandleraz.gov/).  Watching the traffic with fiddler indicates the app is hosted at Esri, but uses a proxy that points to Chandler.  Maybe try emailing them.

Comment: Interesting, looks like they maybe using the proxy for security; just to control authorized access to the services maybe?

Answer (score -1):

I would call the specific city to get their latest zoning layer.  Most cities offer their GIS data for free.

[Phoenix GIS](http://phoenix.gov/webpmo.html)